# In set $E$, If $\{y_j\} \to y \in E$ where $y_j$ is an upper bound of $E$ ...

Tags: analysis, limits

I am trying to prove the following.

> In set $E$, If $\{y_j\} \to y \in E$ where $y_j$ is an upper bound of $E$ and if $\{x_j\} \to y$ where $\forall j,  x_j \in E $, show that $y$ is the supremum of $E$.

This is what I tried. (edited)

We want to show that $y$ is the supremum of $E$, so we will assume the contrary.

Then since $y \in E$ there must be another supremum of $E$ such that 
$$  \sup E > y$$.

Let $\delta = \min(|y-\sup E|,|y-\inf E|)$.

Since all terms of $\{x_j\} \to y$ and $\{y_j\} \to y$, there exists $m$ such that for any given $\epsilon >0$, particularly less than $\delta$, 
$$|x_j - y_j|< \epsilon, \forall j >m$$.

This $y_j$ will be less than $\sup E$, but that contradicts the fact that $y_j$ is an upper bound of $E$.

Comment: At the very least, the first sentence of what you tried needs revision. The given hypotheses do not imply that $(\forall \epsilon>0)\,y-\epsilon\in E$.  Nor does the contrary assumption $y-\epsilon\notin E$ imply that $y-\epsilon$ must be an upper bound of $E$.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I think I know what you're talking about so I will look at the definitions of lub's and stuff a little more carefully.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I worked out the problem differently, does this look better? Do you think I should re-post this question as another question ?

Comment: Are you sure that you're given $y\in E$ in this problem?  (The reason I ask is that it makes the hypotheses about the $x_j$ sequence superfluous.)

Comment: Oops, $y$ is just a limit of both sequences. I can see how my proof will collapse because of this, so I guess I will work on it again.